# split list values into columns :python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
dataframe
input_df :     col_x          col_y
               msg1           [index 12 Score 0.14788]
               msg2           [index 4  Score 0.002986]


output_df:     col_x        index      Score
               msg1         12         0.14788
               msg2         4          0.002986
Approach
1. replace whitespace with ','
input_df['col_y'] = input_df['col_y'].str.replace(' ',',')
2. removing text keeping only value
data['col_y'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\D',value=r'')
3. str split
input_df[['index','score']] = input_df.col_y.str.split(expand=True)
```

i am trying to convert a row values in to columns need to extract the values into separate columns, tried multiple ways nothing seem to work as expected posting here for any better solution.

Comment: Post a demo df in your code. Post what you tried as code.

Comment: @PatrickArtner added demo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's the best option, but I did it using regex:
(Assuming your last column always looks like '[index 12 Score 0.14788]')

```
import pandas as pd
import re

dfData = {
  'col_x' : ['msg1', 'msg2'],
  'col_y' : ['[index 12 Score 0.14788]', '[index 4  Score 0.002986]'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dfData)

indexes = []
scores = []

for i in df.col_y:
    infos = re.search('\[index (.+) Score (.+)\]', i)
    indexes.append(infos.group(1))
    scores.append(infos.group(2))

df['index'] = indexes
df['score'] = scores
df.drop('col_y', axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.head()
```

Comment: thank you @ Pauline . the solution given is simple and easy to understand. keep doing your great work! happy learning

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: pattern = r"\[index\s+(\d+)\s+Score\s+(.+)]"

In [2]: output_df = input_df[["col_x"]] \
   ...:                 .join(input_df.col_y.str.extract(pattern)) \
   ...:                 .rename({0: "index", 1: "Score"}, axis=1) \
   ...:                 .astype({"index": int, "Score": float})
```

---

*Your input dataframe and the result:*

```
In [3]: input_df
```

> ```
>   col_x                      col_y
> 0  msg1   [index 12 Score 0.14788]
> 1  msg2  [index 4  Score 0.002986]
> ```

```
In [4]: output_df
```

> ```
>   col_x  index     Score
> 0  msg1     12  0.147880
> 1  msg2      4  0.002986
> ```

---

*The explanation:*

I used the `.str.extact()` method of Series for your `col_y` column:

```
input_df.col_y.str.extract(pattern)
```

with `pattern` (a regular expression)

```
\[index\s+(\d+)\s+Score\s+(.+)]
```

There are *2 capturing groups* in it:

- `(\d+)` for the value of index,
- `(.+)` for the value of Score,

so the `.str.extract()` created a new dataframe *with 2 columns* — one for each capturing group.

Then I

- joined it with the 1<sup>st</sup> column of your original dataframe:

  ```
  input_df[["col_x"]].join(input_df.col_y.str.extract(pattern)) ,
  ```
- renamed the extracted columns:

  ```
  .rename({0: "index", 1: "Score"}, axis=1)
  ```
- changed their data types:

  ```
  .astype({"index": int, "Score": float})
  ```

---

```
  In [5]: output_df.dtypes
```

> ```
> col_x     object
> index      int32
> Score    float64
> dtype: object
> ```